# GCC - memcpy automatically copies null character?

Tags: c, gcc

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) about `memcpy`: "The function does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly num bytes."

So the following code should give a runtime error, isn't it?

```
char str1[20] = "";
char str2[20] = "Another Text---";

memcpy(str1, str2, strlen(str2));
printf("%s\n%s", str1, str2);
```

But I am always getting the correct output from this code with my gcc compiler. Does this mean memcpy actually copying the null character from the end of `str2` or it's just a random case?

**EDIT:** I get the same behavior with `str1[20] = "A"`, as some answers are pointing out that `str1[20] = ""` is initializing the string with all NULL characters.

Comment: num bytes in your case is the length of "Another Text---" so copying that amount of chars from buffer str2 to buffer str1 won't cause a runtime error. However if str1 is not initialized to null's then using str1 as a null terminated string will cause a crash (probably).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key ingredient in the puzzle is the intializer `""`. This is identical to:

```
char str1[20] = { 0 };
```

This in turn is identical to (at least in GCC, and always in C++):

```
char str1[20] = { };
```

or

```
char str1[20] = { 0, 0, 0, ..., 0 };   // 20 times
```

All of those initializers initialize the array to hold twenty zeros.

The `memcpy` call does *not* copy the null terminator (since `strlen` doesn't count it), but the destination array is properly zeroed out in the first place, so all is well.

Comment: It shouldn't case a runtime error even with out the intializer, it just means there would be junk at the end of the string in str1, so maybe it will explode when giving that buffer to something that expects a null terminated string.

Comment: +1, but the `{}` initializer is not correct for C, it only exist in C++, unfortunately.

Comment: If you look in the debugger you'll see the end of your string is populated with A's. As I've said if you use strcpy or anything else that expects a null terminated string it will more than likely crash.

Comment: It's not identical to `char str1[20] = { };` because `char str1[20] = { };` is malformed C (a constraint violation).

Comment: @Rafi: C99, 6.7.8.21 *"If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or **fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array**, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."* Objects that have static storage duration are zero-initialized.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Empty initializer lists are supported by a gcc extension (question is tagged gcc).

Comment: @R..: Ah, thanks, I thought empty brace initializers were allowed in the more recent C, but I was mistaken. I added a note that it's a GCC extension.

Comment: @Rafi: `char s[20] = "A";` is the same as `char s[20] = { 'A', 0, 0, ..., 0};`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: C has `{0}`, whose behavior is identical to the behavior of `{}` in C++ (default initialization of all elements). So I don't really see any reason the omission of `{}` from C is "unfortunate" except for folks who want to write code in the language that's the intersection of C and C++.

Comment: @R.. I completely aggree, this is one of the things I already have on my list of gratuitous discrepancies between the two languages: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/defects-and-improvements/

Answer (score 1):

memcpy is copying strlen(str2) (this doesn't mean the null byte is copied though) bytes from str2 into str1. Since there is plenty of room in str1 for that many bytes it works. memcpy copies the memory *exactly* as it says.

You would get an error if you tried copying anything longer than 20 from one to the other. You shouldn't store more than 19 chars in either variable either.

As kerrek explained, it also helps you have str1 initialized to nulls as you don't have to worry about the null termination in this specific case.

Comment: This answer misses the point, Kerrek's explains it better and in particular the fact that the target buffer is already `0` initialized is essential to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You've told it to copy strlen(str2) number of chars, which happens to be the length of the string (the null index).

Its the same as using strcpy(). What its trying to say is that if you *need* to copy NULL's you can use memcpy as strcpy() will stop at the first null it finds.

Answer (score 1):

initialize the `str1` with a string **larger than** `str2` and try it again and you see how it does not copy the null. you were just lucky that `str1` is zero filled. I changed the code to show the dependency of the output to content of `str1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[20] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    char str2[20] = "Another Text---";

    memcpy(str1, str2, strlen(str2));
    printf("%s\n%s", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
Another Text---xxxx
Another Text---
```